# Python - Selenium works in Prompt but not in Scripts

Tags: python, selenium, path, sys

```
(base) C:\Users\ac34450\Automation\Python>testENV.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ac34450\Automation\Python\testENV.py", line 15, in <module>
    import RFMlib as rfm
  File "C:\Users\ac34450\Automation\Python\RFMlib.py", line 13, in <module>
    from selenium import webdriver as web
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'selenium'

(base) C:\Users\ac34450\Automation\Python>python
Python 3.7.4 (default, Aug  9 2019, 18:22:51) [MSC v.1915 32 bit (Intel)] :: Anaconda, Inc. on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>import selenium
>>>

(base) C:\Users\ac34450>path
PATH=C:\Users\ac34450\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3;C:\Users\ac34450\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\Library\mingw-w64\bin;C:\Users\ac34450\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\Library\usr\bin;C:\Users\ac34450\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\Library\bin;C:\Users\ac34450\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\Scripts;C:\Users\ac34450\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\bin;C:\Users\ac34450\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\condabin;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;C:\Program Files (x86)\Plantronics\Spokes3G;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;**C:\Users\ac34450\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages**;C:\Users\ac34450\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3;C:\Users\ac34450\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\Scripts;C:\Users\ac34450\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Scripts;C:\Users\ac34450\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\Library\mingw-w64\bin;C:\Users\ac34450\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\Library\usr\bin;C:\Users\ac34450\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\Library\bin;

(base) C:\Users\ac34450\Automation\Python>pip install -U selenium
Requirement already up-to-date: selenium in **c:\users\ac34450\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (3.141.0)**
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: urllib3 in c:\users\ac34450\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from selenium) (1.24.2)
```

I have no idea what is going on here; I have been digging through articles on this site to figure out why my script won't import selenium, but my prompt will. Using Anaconda Prompt. Prompt returns path where selenium module is store and I have my path pointing right to it. My other laptop has an identical setup and there is no issue. I'm hoping there is an article I missed...